# How do I stabilize the sound of a jquery volume - slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html5 webpage, with a slider and an audio track.
I do not reffer to the sound tag property controls = "controls" ().
I want my slider to control the volume from the audio file.
If I use in my body tags , the following code it`s working perfectly.
If I use in my body tags , the result is a deafening noise . This is my code:

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<title>Rain</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body onLoad="run();">

<div id="slider"></div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
// Invoke new Audio object
var ad = new Audio('rainloop.mp3');

//default play audio
ad.play();

//volume slider
$('#slider').slider({
min:0,
max:100,
step:1,
value:50,
slide: function(){

    ad.volume = parseFloat(this.value / 10);
}
```

}
);

I think the problem it`s here : ad.volume = parseFloat(this.value / 10);
I`ve tried also :  ad.volume = parseFloat(this.value) and  ad.volume = parseFloat(this.value / 100) and it`s still making a incomprehensible noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try manipulate volume value between 0 and 1 where 0 is silent (0%) and 1 is max volume (100%)
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/av_prop_volume.asp

Check in console log what You get in this part of code:

```
parseFloat(this.value / 100)
```